# Mixture of simple past and present in the same sentence

Tags: grammaticality, sequence-of-tenses

> And it just recently awarded a million dollar contract that reeks of corruption.

Is the above sentence grammatically correct? The word *recently* is used, which normally establishes a relation between past and present. So is it okay to use simple past in that sentence?

Comment: Try to rewrite everything you say with *above* not to use *above*. Try using words like *this* and *that*.

Comment: Yes—"just recently" means "in the recent past"; so the act of awarding the contract occurred in the past (hence the use of past tense for that part of the sentence), but, according to the author, the contract still smells bad today (hence the use present tense for that part of the sentence).